# How do I get text/words to roll over into the next line, leaving the current line unjustified?

Tags: page-layout, typesetting

How do I get text/words on a page to flow into the next line, mid-word without Pages (Mac) automatically justifying?

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic here. Try searching over on the [Apple SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is this program specific in any way? InDesign? Illustrator... Photoshop...?

Comment: Apple's Pages is a hybrid between text processor and page layout app. So, I don't think it should be shunned here just because it's not Adobe…

Comment: It's true, however, that Pages questions are far more frequent over at the Apple.Stackexchange.

Comment: This is actually a generic software-agnostic design question masquerading as a question about Pages, though I find some of the wording vaguely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a **line break** (also known as 'soft return') by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. Different from a paragraph break (Return key alone) or a column break, the line break doesn't end the current paragraph, which has consequences when using paragraph styles or automatic numbering / bullet lists.